# Filtering code example optimization issue in Django Rest Framework (DRF) or Not

Tags: django, optimization, django-rest-framework, filtering, django-orm

Recently I came up with the following code in DRF documentation for filtering the queryset in an APIListView,

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
        by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
        """
        queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(purchaser__username=username)
        return queryset
```

It seems if the above code snippet is written as follow, it will be more efficient,

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
        by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
        """
        queryset = None
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(purchaser__username=username)
        else:
            queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

Am wrong ? or am i miss something about Django ORM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the queryset is not evaluated, there is no database activity.

To answer the question: No, the second code example is not actually more efficient.

Example:

```py
qs = Model.objects.all()  # no database activity

qs = qs.filter(**some_filter)  # still no activity

list(qs)  # data is being fetched now

qs = qs.filter(**other_filter)  # no new activity

list(qs)  # new activity again
```

Also see [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).